# Can a Druid turn into a Giant Squid then cast Air Walk?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape

Is it possible as a druid to wild shape into a Giant Squid and cast Air Walk on myself to allow myself to use this form above land? And if so, what would my movement speed be.

Comment: So you want to be a...  Blooper?

Comment: Might I suggest sky swim instead of air walk? Air walk lets you, "tread on air as if walking on solid ground." Because squids cannot walk on solid ground, this opens the door for the GM to screw with you. Sky swim is also 1 level lower than air walk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's complicated for a [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/) to use the [supernatural ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) wild shape to assume the form of a [giant squid](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/squid.html#squid-giant) then cast the spell [*air walk*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/airWalk.html) to move about through the air. That's because [a druid can't normally cast spells while having used wild shape to assume the form of an animal](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69985/8610). However, with enough planning and resources, this sequence *is* legit. I suspect, though, the druid will find it easier *first* to cast *air walk* and *then* to use the supernatural ability wild shape to assume the form of a giant squid.

I also suspect that the GM will likely rule that unless the druid casts the spell [*air breathing*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/air-breathing/) or employs a similar effect so that the druid in squid form can also breathe air, the druid in giant squid form will essentially have to hold its breath while on land. That is, a normal giant squid possesses the subtype [aquatic](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/creatureTypes.html#aquatic-subtype) yet *not* the special quality [amphibious](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/universalMonsterRules.html#amphibious). However, a druid that uses wild shape to assume the form of a creature with a swim speed gains the ability to breathe water and, apparently, does not *lose* the ability to breathe air! This may be an oversight that the GM is quick to correct—much to many druid players' dismay—, but a druid player may argue that the ability of assumed aquatic forms to continue to breathe air is a failsafe against a druid being mind controlled into assuming forms that could otherwise kill the druid. Ask the GM.

This GM would have a druid that uses wild shape to assume the form of giant squid then that casts the spell *air walk* to move about outside the water use the giant squid's swim speed as the speed of the *air walk* effect (limited by the druid's ability to emulate that speed as per the restrictions of the supernatural ability wild shape). That is, after all, a giant squid's *only*—therefore normal—speed. (Compare to the Sage's ruling for *D&D 3e* in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100238/8610) about flying through water.) Speed is, however, a complicated concept in *Pathfinder* and its antecedents, so go with the GM's ruling: the fewer discussions one has about *normal speed*, the better.

***Note:*** While this GM would allow the air walk *spell to be used by a druid in giant squid from, I suspect many GMs would prefer the druid employ the* [sky swim](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sky-swim/) *spell for the druid's flying squid needs, that spell—unlike the* air walk *spell—seemingly designed with such creatures in mind. The* sky swim *spell's advantage is it's one spell level lower than the* air walk *spell, but it's disadvantage is it has 1/10 the duration of the* air walk *spell. (Thanks to [Bobtheaverage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/27590/bobtheaverage) for bringing the* sky swim *spell to my attention, and [Oblivious Sage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3548/oblivious-sage) for pointing out the differences between the two spells' durations.).*

Comment: Hmm essentially one would need to cast two spells to get the desired result

Comment: @Atalius If the desired result is being an air squid long-term, *probably* … unless the GM buys the druid player's argument that a druid that assumes giant squid form can still breathe air.

Comment: It is possible to grapple a for in the air?

Comment: @Atalius I'm not sure I understand. A creature that's flying can make grapple attempts against nonflying victims, sure. A creature that's not flying can make grapple attempts against a flying victim if the flier's close to it, sure. A flying creature that tries to *fly away* with the victim it's grappled *is* subject to some controversy but is — in the abstract, in some cases — *possible*, certainly.

Comment: Just one last question Mr.IcanChan, the damage listed for the giant squids 'tentacles' attack is 4D6+3 which would tell me its a secondary attack. However its constrict is at 4D6 +10. Its primary attack the Bite deals 2D6+7. How do they get 4D6+10 on the constrict which would mean its 1.5x damage. Would a wild shaped druid also benefit from this 1.5X constriction damage?

Comment: @Atalius Once a druid can use wild shape to use an effect like *beast shape III* (usually at level 8), the druid when he wild shapes can get a creature's constrict attack. Unless otherwise stated, that constrict attack *should* work just like that of the assumed form. However, *How is the constrict damage of the giant squid determined?* should be its own question.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Comment: I dont think you lose the ability to breath air while polymorphed into an aquatic creature. From polymorph, it says you maintain, but not that you lose: *"If the form grants a swim or burrow speed, you maintain the ability to breathe if you are swimming or burrowing."*  Also remember that polymorph effects usually do not change your creature type.

Comment: Also, together with Natural Spell, Wild Speech will allow a druid to cast spells while polymorphed.

Comment: @ShadowKras *If the form grants a swim or burrow speed, you maintain the ability to breathe if you are swimming or burrowing* is *so* vague, though, that I have to leave that to the GM to decide. I mean, if a form grants a swim speed and you're not swimming, what happens, right? (I think that's to prevent the druid from drowning while in octopus form or whatever, but I'm not sure it's *also* to prevent the druid from *suffocating on land* while in octopus form!) And while type is unchanged, subtypes *are* unmentioned. It's why, ultimately, I leave it to the GM.

Comment: @ShadowKras (And I *know* that Natural Spell *et al.* allow casting spells while using wild shape. That's addressed by *planning and resources* in the first 'graph. I remain pretty sure that's not the question's thrust, though, so I don't feel the need to belabor it.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan the subtype receives the same treatment as the type, due to it not being mention on what changes while polymorphed. So if the GM rules that the subtype is changed, then I don't see why they would rule that the type is unchanged. But i get your point.