# How does the synergist witch's symbiosis interact with wildshape

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102182/can-a-druid-turn-into-a-giant-squid-then-cast-air-walk) got me thinking about ways to let a druid wildshaped into a giant squid walk or fly permanently.

While searching for ways I stumbled upon the [synergist witch](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Witch%20Synergist).

It can merge with her familiar using her symbiosis ability and gets some of her familiar's abilities while doing so. One of them is:

> At 11th level, during symbiosis the synergist gains any abilities the
>   familiar possesses that are listed under beast shape III. If the
>   familiar can fly, the synergist can fly for an unlimited amount of
>   time each day while in symbiosis.

Is there any reason for symbiosis to not work during wildshape? It is not an ability based on her normal form because it is an ability she gets from merging with her familiar.

Because of the high levels in both druid and witch this is probably something only relevant as a thought experiment.
At first I thought 5 levels synergist were enough to get a walking speed untill I rechecked and had to notice that nothing in the form of a walking speed was listed under beast shape.

Answer (score 3):

Changing shape only affects certain racial abilities and other abilities that depend on your form, unless the spell or effect explicitly affects other abilities.

From the [Magic rules (polymorph subshool)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) :

> While under the effects of a polymorph spell, you lose all
>   extraordinary and supernatural abilities that depend on your original
>   form (such as keen senses, scent, and darkvision), as well as any
>   natural attacks and movement types possessed by your original form.
>   You also lose any class features that depend upon form, but those that
>   allow you to add features (such as sorcerers that can grow claws)
>   still function. While most of these should be obvious, the GM is the
>   final arbiter of what abilities depend on form and are lost when a new
>   form is assumed. Your new form might restore a number of these
>   abilities if they are possessed by the new form.

Any ability that doesn't explicitly require a specific anatomy (like casting spells with somatic components, requires hands) is still fully usable. Then even when wildshaped, your character can use symbiosis and every ability it gives.